# FX Risk Reversal - RHS/LHS - Strike adjustments

Tags: fixed-income, fx, risk, risk-management, fxo

I was wondering why ppl use the wordings being „rhs/LHS“ right hand side / left hand side when having an risk reversal for example Long EUR Call / USD Put and Short EUR Put / USD Call. Do they refer to the delta? and how do I know in which way to adjust the strike of the sold option in order to make it more valuable/ less valuable?

Comment: In reference to an FX quotation such as EURUSD, LHS refers to the *underlying* or *base* or *transacted* currency the EUR, and RHS refers to the *numeraire* or *quote* currency i.e. the USD. Then for options the "RHS Delta" would be the USD delta etc. and similarly for "RHS strike" etc.

Comment: For a call the lower the strike the more costly the option, for a put the higher the strike the more costly the option. In both cases the more ITM, the more costly.

Comment: The *Dual Delta* of an option gives you a first order approximation of how much an option's value would increase if you move the strike a small amount.